# Can't copy the beginning (first 64 bytes) of one .wav to an empty one

Tags: c, file, binary-data

I have to copy first 64 bytes from input file **in.wav** into output file **out.wav**.
(I've downloaded a *program* which shows .wav file's header (chunks): first 44 bytes and first 20 bytes of data_subchunk)

My code fills out.wav file with some values, but (I'm convinced) it to be a garbage. (The values that *program* shows don't match.)

I have to copy a part of **in.wav** file into **out.wav**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct FMT
{
    char        Subchunk1ID[4];
    int         Subchunk1Size;
    short int   AudioFormat;
    short int   NumChannels;
    int         SampleRate;
    int         ByteRate;
    short int   BlockAlign;
    short int   BitsPerSample;

} fmt;

typedef struct DATA
{
    char        Subchunk2ID[4];
    int         Subchunk2Size;
    int         Data[441000]; // 10 secs of garbage. he-he)
} data;

struct HEADER
{
    char        ChunkId[4];
    int         ChunkSize;
    char        Format[4];
    fmt         S1;
    data        S2;
} header;


int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen("in.wav", "r");
    FILE *output = fopen("out.wav", "w");

    if(input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open wave file\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

        fwrite(&input, sizeof(int), 16, output); // 16'ints' * 4 = 64 bytes

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: When copying binary data, preferably use `open`, `read`, and `write` instead of their `f-` equivalents!

Comment: Why are you `fopen()`ing `in.waw` **twice?**

Comment: You have to _read_ your 64 bytes from input file first (into a memory buffer), and then write this buffer to the output file. In your code you just copy the content of output pointer, that has nothing to do with file content.

Comment: I'll delete one 'fopen' now..

Comment: Or at least open the files in _binary_ mode.

Comment: You have a few potential bugs here ; first, your are `fopen`ing "in.wav" twice into `input`, which is bag. Next, you are not checking whether `output` contains something or not, which might be disastrous. `fwrite` might fail, too.

Comment: `fwrite(&input, sizeof(int), 16, output);` doesn't look appropriate.

Comment: Don't use open/read/write unless you have a reason to do so, since they are Linux (unix?) specific. fopen/fread/fwrite are C standard and available on all platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing data to opened output file from input

```
fwrite(&input, sizeof(int), 16, output);
```

I am not sure, if you can use FILE pointer this way. I would do that this way

```
unsigned char buf[64];
fread(&buf, sizeof(char), 64, input);
fwrite(&buf, sizeof(char), 64, output);
```

Also open files in binary mode: `fopen("in.wav", "rb")` and `fopen("out.wav", "wb")`

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Comment: I made them because of better change of code, If @Julian want to read dynamic size.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a `FILE` pointer as input to `fwrite`. You actually have to *read* the data first into a buffer, before you write that buffer.

Answer (score 1):

First, use *binary mode* for `fopen` (`"wb"` instead of `"w"`). Second, you are making an unsafe assumption, that is `sizeof (int) == 4`, which is not always true. Third, `input` is already a pointer, you don't need the `&` befor `input` on the `fwrite` line.

And, **most importantly**, you cannot use `fwrite` from one file handle to another. You need to copy to a `char[]` buffer before, like:

```
char buffer[40];
if (fread(buffer, sizeof (char), 40, input) != 40) {
    printf("Error!");
}
if (fwrite(buffer, sizeof (char), 40, output) != 40) {
    printf("Error!");
}
```